# Shell script: Parallelizing commands in bash script under Ubuntu linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am creating a bash script to losslessly compress jpeg and png files, so I use two package under Ubuntu named *jpegoptim* and *optipng*. A will use the script with **2 or 4 core** processors. I would like to use the full capacity of my CPU.

The problem is that *optipng* does not support multithreading by default (it only uses one CPU core), so I decided, I launch **2 or 4 parallel processes** to compress the images faster. I already sorted the image files to 4 almost equal arrays (based on number of pixels), and now I need to run the processes parallelized.

I am trying parallelizing the processes with the `&` character at the end of the command, but it does not do the job parallel.

```
optipngout=$(optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_1[@]} &)
optipngout=$(optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_2[@]} &)
optipngout=$(optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_3[@]} &)
optipngout=$(optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_4[@]} &)
```

I have to catch the output of the command, so I think the problem is with the $() structure.

Comment: I don't think bash has concurrency support, but I could be mistaken. Any reason you can't use a full programming language?

Comment: The util [`taskset`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/taskset1.html) is something you might look into.  Although I must say, I haven't been able to realize much benefit if any in my limited use of it.  Also, the term "processor affinity" might help you in your searches.

Comment: @jedwards it is working very well with the `&` character. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Gnu parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/). It allows you to do what you want with only small modifications to your existing script.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with the `taskset` and `&` commands. Thanks for [@jedwards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736937/jedwards)

The final code looks like this:

```
outstr=$(taskset 0xFFFFFFFF optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_1[@]}) &
outstr=$(taskset 0xFFFFFFFF optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_2[@]}) &
outstr=$(taskset 0xFFFFFFFF optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_3[@]}) &
outstr=$(taskset 0xFFFFFFFF optipng -$pnglevel -dir $outdir ${threaddata_4[@]}) &
```